# Send UDP packet and listen for replies

Tags: udp, socat

I have a program with a *Send an UDP packet to port `xyz` and I will reply with some UDP packets!* interface.

I've found out that I can send a UDP packet with

```
echo <packetContent> | socat - udp:<dstIP>:<dstPort>,sp=<srcPort>
```

and listen (= just dump their content to stdout) for UDP packets with

```
socat - udp-listen:<srcPortFromPreviousLine>
```

But how can I bring those two together? When I start the listening part in one window at first, the port is already in use and I cannot send anything from there in another window.

Comment: Isn't `udp:` already bidirectional?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brought me to the solution. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like grawity said in the comment, `udp:` is bidirectional. So I can just use one command:

```
echo <packetContent> | socat -t 10 - udp:<dstIp>:<dstPort>,sp:<srcPort>
```

This sends the packet and prints any packets coming back from there; if none arrive, it quits after 10 seconds (`-t 10`).

Comment: `echo <packetContent> | socat -t 10 - udp:<dstIp>:<dstPort>,sp:<srcPort>` doesn't print out any answer for me... also it returns the error message `socat[...] E parseopts_table(): unknown option "sp:3702"`...  it should probably be an equals sign instead (`...,sp=<srcPort>`).

Answer (score 1):

If supported, use `reuseaddr` with both commands. They will be like

```
echo <packetContent> | socat - udp:<dstIP>:<dstPort>,sp=<srcPort>,reuseaddr
socat - udp-listen:<srcPortFromPreviousLine>,reuseaddr
```

From `man 1 socat`:

> `reuseaddr`
>   Allows other sockets to bind to an address even if parts of it (e.g. the local port) are already in use by `socat`.